# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException issue in Android

Tags: java, android

I am checking internet on splash activity and if internet available I am checking server is online or not with below method

```
private void serverCall() {
    database = DAO.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); //added by eagleeyes
    pref = new Setting_preference(this);
    if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
        pref.editor.putBoolean("sound", true);
        pref.editor.putBoolean("vibrate", true);

        if (NetworkCheck.isInternetAvailable(SplashsActivity.this)) {
            if (NetworkCheck.IsReachable(SplashsActivity.this)){
                new DownloadLatestData().execute();
            }
            else {
                if (database.isDataBaseCreated()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    connectionerror();
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (database.isDataBaseCreated()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            } else {
                connectionerror();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error that

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Because of server check on Main Thread. I have thought lot of option but I have not got any perfect idea for solve it. My server checking code is like below

```
public static boolean IsReachable(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo netInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isReachable = false;

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        // Some sort of connection is open, check if server is reachable
        try {
            URL url = new URL(DataManager.SIMPLE_BASE_URL);
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(10 * 2000);
            urlc.connect();
            isReachable = (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return isReachable;

}
```

What should I do for solve this issue ?

If I use StrictMode policy with below code then its working fine...But I am confuse that I can use it or not.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Let me know someone can help me for come out from this issue. Thanks

Comment: `if (NetworkCheck.IsReachable(SplashsActivity.this)){` is the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Move all your `NetworkCheck` calls into `doInBackground()` of your `DownloadLatestData` task.

Comment: @CommonsWare and if server is not available...its keeping progress dialogue always....How to put condition in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make all network call in a separate background thread. Android has a strict rule on not allowing any network call on main thread. Try implementing your `IsReachable(Context context)` method inside separate thread using class like ***AsyncTask***.

**Edit** You can try like this

```
public class Connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;
    private OnConnectionEstablishedListener mListener;

    public interface OnConnectionEstablishedListener {
        void onConnectionEstablished(boolean isReachable);
    }

    public Connection(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager, OnConnectionEstablishedListener listener) {
        mConnectivityManager = connectivityManager;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final NetworkInfo netInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isReachable = false;

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Some sort of connection is open, check if server is reachable
            try {
                URL url = new URL(DataManager.SIMPLE_BASE_URL);
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(10 * 2000);
                urlc.connect();
                isReachable = (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return isReachable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isReachable) {
        super.onPostExecute(isReachable);
        mListener.onConnectionEstablished(isReachable);
    }
}
```

And your calling Activity should implement `OnConnectionEstablishedListener` like this

```
@Override
public void onConnectionEstablished(boolean isConnected) {
    new DownloadLatestData().execute();
}
```

*Suggestion:* Although this all can be achieved in your `DownloadLatestData` with proper implementation.

Comment: can you give me example of it that How can I use it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice coding and example. I have made connection class. But now confuse in how to use this with my servercall method . You can check how I was using it. Can You please tell me how can I use it with ServerCall ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to check if URL is reachable or not, just call your `new DownloadLatestData().execute();` if network available.

and put the condition in your asynctask if failed or success.